# Specify a descriptive user name in the SVN commit message

Tags: svn, subclipse

Is there a way to configure the SVN client to use a descriptive full name for the user making a commit instead of the log-in user name?

I found that default configuration file that is being used by the SVN client at

**%AppData%\Roaming\Subversion\config**

but it is still not clear how to achieve that.
I hoped there will be an entry like

```
[User]
Jo Do
```

but there isn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Subversion always records the name of the user account committing the change. If you need a more descriptive name, change your account names, or script your other processes that look at the log history to change it for display purposes on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The client does not control the svn:author value, it is set by the server based on how you authenticate with the repository.  So it depends on which server you are using: Apache or svnserve and how you have it configured.  With Apache and LDAP, as an example, you can control which LDAP attribute is used for the username.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapremoteuserattribute